# Wireframe modifier different when applied

Tags: modifiers

Okay so my problem is pretty simple.
I have a flat plane with a wireframe modifier. Works as expected.
Looks like this:
[image: Working as expected]

But when I apply the modifier, the geometry changes.
Now it looks like this:
[image: Not working as expected]

The wireframe appears to be completely flat.

[image: Side view]

As you can see in the first image, there is no scaling, and there are no other modifiers.
What else could cause this issue?

What other info can I share to make answering this easier?

Edit: I uploaded the .blend file here: [removed]

Edit: I removed the file because it was irrelevant to the issue. (see answer)

Comment: pls upload your file

Comment: uploaded the file. Link is in the question now.

Comment: weird, use right click > convert to mesh and it should work... didn't test your file but happens to me on any mesh... bug?

Comment: I tested on a different computer now, before and after updating to 3.1 and it appears to happen to all meshes in this new version. Converting to mesh is a functioning workaround but there is definitely a bug there. Thanks for the tip, good to keep that in mind until the next update.

Comment: @Julinator, upload don't exist...Btw, pls don't update in the answer, you can add comment or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user @alambre pointed out, this appears to happen to all meshes in blender 3.1 when applying the wireframe modifier. Using right click > 'convert to mesh' still works if you want to apply it. (Be aware that this also applies all other modifiers too though.)

Assuming this is a bug, it will probably be resolved in the next update.

Comment: Sorry, should one use convert to mesh before or after applying the modifier?

Comment: Neither. Converting does the applying for you.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you.